# Maximum # of Start Menu Pinned Programs

Tags: windows-7, windows, start-menu, pinning

I am running Windows 7 Professional and I just got a new display with a whole lot more screen space (greater resolution) and I am having a little, rather ridiculous, problem.

I have only have pinned programs in my Start Menu. No recent programs. No recently opened files. I have expanded it to contain 30 items. I can find no Windows 7 setting or registry key to increase it more than 30.

Is 30 items a limitation of Windows 7? Is it a limitation of "Windows 7" only? Or, is it the limitation of the "Professional" version of Windows 7?

I have hunted for a solution here and elsewhere but to no avail. Does anyone know what this is all about?

With thanks,

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you may have reached your limit, just saying. I also don't think that you CAN change the maximum limit for the icons in your Start Menu.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Ah. My bad. I am sorry!

Comment: No problem. It's difficult to judge what to do when you have a comment to make but don't have the rep to post it. Just get asking and answering questions and you'll have the rep in no time.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7 solution maybe, add registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\Start_JumpListItems

And set this DWORD to a number you like, e.g. 60 (dec)

Comment: Do you know for a fact this solution works?  It worries me that you have the word "maybe" in an answer.